# NodeJS Express - Send specific routes to specific cluster workers?

Tags: node.js, express, node-cluster

I have a central API server starting cluster worker instances. Each instance has a specific bigger job, and there might be manipulations I want to do on that specific instance only. This was the rough idea I had in mind:

- API Server with express, master process

  - instance 1: GET /instances/1/*
  - instance 2: GET /instances/2/*

Each instance is a separate worker process, and I was hoping I could delegate all API requests for specific worker, directly to the worker (to execute functions in that worker).

instance/:id does represent the WorkerID.

The client might request the logs where workerID = x, so GET /instances/x/logs.

The goal here is that master routes all requests for instance X to the sub-process identified as x.

This is not for load distribution across workers that are essentially clones/mirrors.

Each of my worker may be performing a variation of a long running task (days, weeks, months long). Methods are shared across all workers, but if I'm calling /instances/x/logs I only want to query that on that specific worker process. That's the goal I'm looking to figure out.

```
// route these to subprocess x
GET /instances/x/logs
POST /instances/x/settings

// route these to subprocess y
GET /instances/y/logs
POST /instances/y/settings

// route these to subprocess z
GET /instances/z/logs
POST /instances/z/settings

// make a new worker process, returns worker ID as reference
POST /instances/
```

I saw I can have multiple express listeners on the same port across different processes, but if I understood correctly, this is automatically load-balanced by express. I can't route specific requests to specific workers based on the path, can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each instance is a separate worker process, and I was hoping I could delegate all API requests for specific worker, directly to the worker (to execute functions in that worker).

Indeed you can do that, but unless your instance/:id represents the WorkerID, you've hit an end.

Let's assume the following example where `:id` is not a worker id:

**W** - Worker

**W1**`/instances/1/:method` - has the following methods `names`, `cities`, `cars`

**W2**`/instances/2/:method` - has the following methods `names`, `fruits`, `stats`

The HTTP client will want to access:

1. `GET /instances/1/name`, that's great, `name` exists in both paths. - **TRUE**
2. `GET /instances/2/fruits`, that's great, `fruits` exists in this path on **W2**, **BUT** if the balancer serves you **W1** with that route you'll have an error, because `fruits` doesn't exist on **W1** - **FALSE**

**Final answer**:

You cannot request workers to pop-up and serve your will, best you can do is some communication between master & workers or have some methods that requires some processing, and based on the CPU usage, trigger those methods when a low worker is served. But take a look at the good part, if they die, you can `fork` new ones without crashing your whole app.

Comment: instance/:id does represent the WorkerID. The client might request the logs where workerID = x, so GET /instance/x/logs. The goal here is that master routes all requests for instance X to the sub-process identified as WX.

Your scenario works for load distribution across workers that are essentially clones/mirrors. Each of my worker may be performing a variation of a long running task (days, weeks, months long). Methods are shared across all workers, but if I'm calling `/instance/x/logs` I only want to query that on that specific worker process. That's the goal I'm looking to figure out.

Comment: Expanded my question for clarity I hope! Would you have any ideas on approaching this? A last resort I was thinking was exposing a dedicated REST server and websocket server on each worker, and ensuring the parent process knows the unique port and IP of each worker. Wonder if that's overkill though.

Comment: Expose the worker id's as headers !  `res.setHeader('Worker-ID', cluster.worker.id)` . I think you can even set them in process.env or some global. I did something like this couple of years ago and i went with WID in headers.

Comment: And it gets even better with headers because you can remove the `:id` from your URL, the new link will be just `/instances/logs`. One less segment, one less worry. I renounced though the idea of workers in small apps for example, because each worker spawned consumes about ~9-10MB of memory.

Comment: I do still need things to work as workers though. One worker might fully max out cpu usage on that core. I don't mind the delay until that workers done, on that thread, but I don't want it to affect any other logic from the other workers. 

Regarding your setHeader suggestion, would how would I route the request ot the worker though? I thought multiple express instances listening on the same port just means automatic load balancing - i have no control which worker will try to handle that route/request, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I saw this for what looks like a raw TCP connection, curious if there's something similar for workers. So I know worker ID x is the worker with process ID y, that's I find that worker from my memory of workers and make that handle this express route (since it's under /instances/x/...): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339915/pass-request-to-specific-forked-node-instance

Comment: Node.JS 10 has an experimental module, https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html , haven't tried it, still using 8. And then there is this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-worker